# Flutter. Error Instance of Model / how to get nested data from server

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to print everything I get from the model. But instead of all the data, I only get the data of the first level.
Here is what I get from the server -

```
"categories": [
        {
            "name": "Dlya nego",
            "url": "dlya-nego/",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "obyv",
                    "url": "/dlya-nego/obuv/",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Krossovki",
                            "url": "/dlya-nego/obuv/krossovki/",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "slancy",
                            "url": "/dlya-nego/obuv/slancy/",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Kurtki",
                    "url": "/dlya-nego/Kurtki/",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "bombery",
                            "url": "/dlya-nego/Kurtki/bombery/",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "dlya nee",
            "url": "/dlya-nee/",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "obyv",
                    "url": "/dlya-nee/obuv/",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Krossovki",
                            "url": "/dlya-nee/obuv/krossovki/",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
```

there are still a few layers, but they are identical

here are my models -

```
class CatalogDrawerModel extends CatalogDrawerEntity {
  const CatalogDrawerModel({
    required name,
    required url,
    required one
}) : super (
    name: name,
    url: url,
    one: one
  );

  factory CatalogDrawerModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return CatalogDrawerModel(
        name: json['name'],
        url: json['url'],
        one: json['children'] != null
        ? (json['children'] as List<dynamic>).map((json) => OneModel.fromJson(json)).toList()
            : null
    );
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'url': url,
      'children': one
    };
  }
}
```

and

```
class OneModel extends OneChildren{
  OneModel({name, url, two}) : super (name: name, url: url, two: two);

  factory OneModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return OneModel(
      name: json['name'],
      url: json['url'],
      two: json['children'] != null
        ? (json['children'] as List<dynamic>).map((json) => TwoModel.fromJson(json)).toList()
          : null
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'url': url,
      'two': two
    };
  }
}

class TwoModel extends TwoChildren{
  TwoModel({name, url}) : super (name: name, url: url);

  factory TwoModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return TwoModel(
      name: json['name'],
      url: json['url']
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'url': url
    };
  }
}
```

here is what I print in the console -

```
I/flutter ( 2825): catalogDrawer[index] = CatalogDrawerModel(Dlya nego, /dlya-nego/, [Instance of 'OneModel', Instance of 'OneModel'])
I/flutter ( 2825): catalogDrawer[index] = CatalogDrawerModel(dlya nee, /dlya-nee/, [Instance of 'OneModel'])
I/flutter ( 2825): catalogDrawer[index] = CatalogDrawerModel(deti, /deti/, [Instance of 'OneModel'])
I/flutter ( 2825): catalogDrawer[index] = CatalogDrawerModel(Sale, /sale/, [Instance of 'OneModel'])
```

here is how I display it -

```
itemCount: catalogDrawer.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  print('catalogDrawer[index] = ${catalogDrawer[index]}');
```

**As a result**. I can't access catalogDrawer[index].one[index].name

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

When you are decoding json use like this

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          List jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body)['content'];

          return jsonResponse.map((data) => Content.fromJson(data)).toList();
}
```

> ['content']

is the field in json

> Content

is the model class in your case CatalogDrawerModel

Comment: `if(response.statusCode == 200) {
       List catalogDrawer = json.decode(response.body)['categories'];
       return catalogDrawer.map((data) => CatalogDrawerModel.fromJson(data)).toList();
       // final catalogDrawer= json.decode(response.body);
       // print('Data for cards - $catalogDrawer');
       // return (catalogDrawer['categories'] as List).map((e) => CatalogDrawerModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
     } else {`

But the output to the console remained the same as in the question